# File upload to document library using powershell and web service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, web-services

I'm trying to upload some files to SharePoint 2013 document library using PowerShell and SharePoint 2013 web services (/_vti_bin/copy.asmx). There is some examples how to use copy.asmx web service  on C# like [this](http://www.daoudisamir.com/from-a-c-application-upload-to-sharepoint-using-a-web-service/) but I want to do this with powershell. How can I do this? How can I use /_vti_bin/copy.asmx web services from PowerShell?

I will upload files to a SharePoint farm which is not in our domain so I need to set username and password.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I've solved my problem to upload file with following code; but I couldn't set the meta data fields of document.

```
$URI = "http://www.example.com/sites/dev/_vti_bin/copy.asmx?WSDL"
$securePasssword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xyz\username", $securePasssword)
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace ILS -Credential $credentials

$data = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestDoc.pdf")

$fields =@()

$field = New-Object -TypeName ILS.FieldInformation
$field.DisplayName="Disp"
$field.InternalName="Title"
$field.Value="t.pdf"

$fields+=$field


$date1 = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"

$results = $null
$proxy.CopyIntoItems(" ","http://www.example.com/sites/Dev/TestLib/TestDoc_$date1.pdf", [ILS.FieldInformation]$fields,$data,[ref] $results)
```

It gives me following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a quick example of how to upload a document on a SharePoint server using the SharePoint PowerShell module which uses the SharePoint Object Model.

```
# Set the variables 
$WebURL = “http://portal.contoso.com/sites/stuff” 
$DocLibName = “Docs” 
$FilePath = “C:\Docs\stuff\Secret Sauce.docx” 

# Get a variable that points to the folder 
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName) 
$Files = $List.Files

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path 
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

# Load the file into a variable 
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint 
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false) 
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but I need to use web services. The farm which the document will be uploaded to is in another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one example From [Todd Klindt blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=487)

```
# Set the variables 
$destination = "http://portal.contoso.com/sites/stuff/Docs” 
$File = get-childitem “C:\Docs\stuff\Secret Sauce.docx”

# Since we’re doing this remotely, we need to authenticate 
$securePasssword = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass@word1" -AsPlainText -Force 
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("contoso\johnsmith", $securePasssword)

# Upload the file 
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials 
$webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $File.Name, "PUT", $File.FullName)
```

Comment: Thank you @Marek, but this did not work for me :(

Comment: Do you receive any error? exception?